# I have a problem with a series, can you help me?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Guys I have to say if $\sum_n\frac{1}{n}\tan\frac{1}{n}$ diverges or not, can you help me and show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{n}\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Comment: More crudely ,since $(\tan x)/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0,$  we have $|\tan (1/n)|<2/n $ for all but finitely many $n$.................+1

Answer (score 1):

Use the comparison test.  When proving the derivative of $\sin$, you most likely derived the following inequality:

$$x<\tan(x)$$

for $x\approx0$.  From this, it follows that for large $x$, we have

$$\frac1x>\tan\left(\frac1x\right)$$

Thus, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\tan\left(\frac1n\right)<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$$

Thus, it converges.

Answer (score 1):

Using the estimates $\sin\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{n}$ and $\cos\frac{1}{n}\geq\cos1$, for $n\geq1$, we have that the *positive series* in question is convergent: 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\tan\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{\cos1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6\cos1}.
$$